# empty file that is over 19% percent full

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script which empties file which is reaches 19% or more. I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

ALERT="19" # setting alert to 19

df -h | grep /tmp | awk '{print $4}' | while read output; # reading the file system
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )

  if [ $usep -gt ALERT ]; then
      cd  /tmp
          cat /dev/null > purge_foreign_mdn.log # filename
  fi
done
```

I am getting this error:

> purge_file.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected

I tried -gt "19" and -gt '19'. Still getting different errors but at the same line.

Comment: `// ...` is not a shell comment.

Comment: You might consider using a tool designed for this.  **logrotate** would be a good candidate...

Comment: `cd /tmp; cat /dev/null > purge.log` is equivalent to `> /tmp/purge.log`.  See: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Like I pointed to Flimzy user I haven't used // in my original script. Sorry for confusion. But I am still getting an error line 3: =19: command not found 33%

Comment: In your comparison, `ALERT` is a string, not a variable.

Comment: purge_file.sh: line 11: /tmp/: Is a directory

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$ALERT`, not `ALERT`.  As it is, you are comparing the `$usep` variable to the string `ALERT`, not the variable called `$ALERT`.

Comment: Ok. I've changed it and this what I get purge_file.sh: line 3: =19: command not found
33%
Obviously the file is now 33 %. I need to empty it when it is 19% or over.

Comment: @user2876750: Be sure to use the valid bash comment character, `#`, not `//`.

Comment: I dont have comments in my orignal script, this was specifically for stack overlow question

Comment: Then be sure to use valid comments on Stackoverflow, so people like me and @chepner aren't confused. :)

Comment: @user2876750: you need to use `$ALERT` in line 10, **not** in line 3.